# CSS transition code

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with this css transition code. It expands to a new height on hover fine, but I need it to go back to it original height when out hover or mouseout. (Like a pencil ad) Currently, on mouseout it stays expanded and the cursor is stuck on the hyperlink. Current page link is http://hswheels.autoconx.com/
Any help would be great appreciated.

```
.grow {
  height: 30px; /* Origional height */
  width: 780px; /* Origional width */
  transition:height 0.5s  ease-in-out; /* Animation time */
  -webkit-transition:height 0.5s  ease-in-out; /* For Safari */
}
.grow:hover {
  height: 345px; /* This is the height on hover */
  background:url('http://www.heraldstandard.com/app/media/wheels/expanded2.jpg')
}
.grow:hover a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none; /* No underlines on the link */
  z-index: 10; /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
  background-color: #FFF; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  opacity: 0; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  filter: alpha(opacity=1); /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have your anchor set to position:absolute, it's taking up the full page.

You simply need to set position:relative on the parent element (in this case .grow) so that the anchor is absolutely positioned to the parent, instead of the page.

```
.grow {
  position:relative;  
  height: 30px; /* Origional height */
  width: 780px; /* Origional width */
  transition:height 0.5s  ease-in-out; /* Animation time */
  -webkit-transition:height 0.5s  ease-in-out; /* For Safari */
}
```

added a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3nuhev2k/2/

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. Here's my [aborted attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/8tryekvo/) just for kicks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the 100% height and 100% width on your link on hover. It is as big as your website.